# Why does `scipy` accept separate `args` for objective functions?

Tags: python, api, lambda, scipy

Python has had lambda expressions since [almost forever](https://www.python.org/download/releases/1.6.1/download/). However, `scipy` and some other libraries follow a [different paradigm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) while accepting a function as an argument, *e.g.*:

```py
def minimize(fun, x0, args=(), [...]):
'''
where:
     args : tuple, optional
            Extra arguments passed to the objective function [...]
'''
...
```

*i.e.*, they accept the extra arguments to be passed to `fun` as a separate list/tuple `args` instead of encouraging usage of `lambda` functions. This seems like one extra argument to reason about in the code which could have been avoided.

Why is that the case? Are lambda functions slower? Or was it just following conventions from other languages like `R` (where one might ask the same question and point to `S`)?

Are there advantages in respecting this choice if I am designing a new API?

Comment: This is very nearly a much broader language design question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at `optimize.minimize` code, I see that it passes the task on to functions like `_minimize_neldermead`.  These in turn make a call like:

```
fcalls, func = wrap_function(func, args)
<more setup>
... = func(x0)
... = func(y)
```

which is (from `scipy/optimize/optimize.py`):

```
def wrap_function(function, args):
    ncalls = [0]
    if function is None:
        return ncalls, None

    def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
        ncalls[0] += 1
        return function(*(wrapper_args + args))

    return ncalls, function_wrapper
```

So `args` are handled by concatenating them to the variables (`wrapper_args`) and passing the tuple to your function.  That's a simple, straight forward wrapping mechanism.

The header for this `.py` file credits

```
# optimize.py module by Travis E. Oliphant
...
# A collection of optimization algorithms.  Version 0.5
# CHANGES
#  Added fminbound (July 2001)
```

Travis is original developer for much of `numpy`.  Note the early change year.  I'm assuming that this wrapper was added long before scipy was installed on the github repository, but you could certainly check.

Describing how the wrapping functions doesn't explain why he chose it. It could be that he was modeling the API after FORTRAN and C packages.  Some of these `scipy` optimization, ode and interpolation functions end up using compiled code.

---

I found a 2013 pull request that changed the syntax of this wrapper function:

```
-    def function_wrapper(x):
+    def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
         ncalls[0] += 1
-        return function(x, *args)
+        return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
```

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/cf3adca80e371fd19a34b398d2f1ed0e19f0cbdc

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3785

Apparently some people have had problems with defining `args` as a list or single item, rather than a tuple. There are SO questions where people use `args=(x)` instead of `args=(x,)`.  An alternative that is mentioned in this `issue` is `functools.partial`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. So it appears that the API design probably was motivated by keeping it close to the original Fortran API. Also taking into account the various issues with the `args` argument, it would appear that there is no advantage to making this design choice for a new API?

Comment: It is still going to wrap it to get the `ncalls` attribute.  But if `partial` or `lambda` works for you, I don't see any reason not to use them.  Guido wanted to remove `lambda` from Python3, but others prevailed.  http://www.python-course.eu/python3_lambda.php

Answer (score 1):

A big part of this is because Python has "half a lambda", not really full-blown lambdas like you may be used to from lisp or Erlang.

Python lambdas are restricted to a single expression*, can't include a certain built-in side-effecty statement, and can't extend to be multi-line without enclosing them in parens. Named functions can be passed freely and can do whatever you might imagine. There is little incentive in a language with semantic whitespace to adjust the rest of the syntax to accommodate lambdas of arbitrary complexity.

Ultimately, Python lambdas can be convenient in certain cases, but they simply are not arbitrarily powerful *by design*.

(It *is* possible by way of parens and line extensions to write big hairy lambdas in place, but extremely messy and unpythonic. These days even in Erlang there is a trend, after years of getting pretty crazy with lambdas in place, to only use lambda definitions to enclose some local state within a call to an externally defined function. Using lamdbas in this way in either language (or lisp) the lambda sweet spot, and provides better traces when something crashes.)

So the compromise is the same as what we find elsewhere in Python: explicitly define functions, then pass them around if you want to.

As for why scipy uses this particular argument passing technique, I imagine it is because they wanted to allow you to define and use arbitrary functions or arbitrary arity, and this is *much* easier to do with named functions than big crazy in-place lambdas that other Python programmers would hate you for defining in place.

Related:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99243/why-doesnt-python-allow-multi-line-lambdas
- [Language Design is Not Just Solving Puzzles](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=147358) (linked in the above)

[* I had erroneously written "single argument" before, Robert Kern corrected me.]

Comment: Python lambdas are most certainly not restricted to a single argument. They can include any function, side effects or no; they can't include a Python 2 `print` statement if that's what you are referring to, but that's not a function.

Comment: @RobertKern Indeed, they are restricted to a single expression, not single argument. And yes, py2 print is a statement, not a function. But nevertheless, they are crippled as far as lambdas go -- but for a reason that was carefully considered, which is a sign of solid design imo.

Comment: The library could still have put the onus of defining a new function on the user and not accepted any extra arguments at all. In fact, keeping in mind that GVR isn't a fan of lambdas himself, I would create a new `def` function to pass in and I think that would be cleaner than passing extra `args` into the function. See also hpaulj's answer and the issues the `tuple` form of `args` has caused. In that case, perhaps a new API will not benefit by keeping that extra `args` around. What do you think?

Comment: @zxq9 The single-expression limitation isn't really relevant here, since the use case here is only to change the arity of the called function, which is always just a single expression: `minimize(f, args=(y, z)) -> minimize(lambda x: f(x, y, z))`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `lambda` functions can be slower, especially if the inner function is a C extension function, which is often the case. The function gets called inside of a relatively tight loop inside the minimizer, so shaving off the overhead of an additional Python function call can help.

`functools.partial()` is a better alternative than `lambda` functions and may be clearer or more convenient than passing `args=` to `minimize()`, but it didn't exist when these APIs were being made many years ago.

Comment: I couldn't find a definitive source which benchmarked the overhead of a lambda function. Wouldn't the overhead be negligible compared to the already existing overhead of jumping over the Python-C barrier? And I suspect that lambda expressions are easier to optimize for JITs (though I may be wrong here). Could you please provide a source? Thanks!

Comment: It would be surprising if the lambda overhead is the cause why `args` was used --- lambda overhead is small, (~ 40ns here), which is likely small compared to other processing done in the optimization routines or in the objective function itself.

Comment: Measurements now may not reflect the relative performance c.a. 2000 which is ultimately where this API choice derived from (Travis Oliphant's multilab which was adopted into scipy, then continued in the newer `minimize()` for consistency). @musically_ut, it depends on the contents of the function, but since the main inputs are generally numpy arrays, there is often little conversion cost. JITted optimizers did not exist at the time the API was made, so that was certainly not a factor then.

Comment: About this time, one [Guido's arguments for introducing list comprehensions](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) to the language was that it was faster than `map(lambda x: some_expression, ...)`, so it certainly was a concern. The additional overhead for a lexically-scoped `lambda` to look up names in the enclosing namespace for the extra arguments led to optimization tricks like `lambda x, y=y, z=z: f(x, y, z)`. Dark, dark days. A lot of optimization has happened in the interpreter since then.